# SUM total amount of each column from two tables SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

By joining two tables, the total amount obtained from Crowdfund_Users is incorrect. Sum of Amount in table Crowdfund_Users increased by an additional 60000 from ID 5.

table Crowdfund_Users (ID is primary key)

| ID | Crowdfund_id | User_id | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 203 | 1232 | 500.00 |
| 2 | 203 | 5436 | 10000.00 |
| 3 | 203 | 4356 | 3000.00 |
| 4 | 203 | 3235 | 5000.00 |
| 5 | 203 | 4523 | 60000.00 |

table Crowdfund_Payments (Crowdfund_User_ID is foreign key)

| ID | Crowdfund_User_ID | Payment_Type | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Cash | 500 | 2022-12-15 18:44:16.783 |
| 2 | 2 | Cash | 10000 | 2022-12-15 18:44:16.783 |
| 3 | 3 | Cash | 3000 | 2022-12-15 18:44:16.783 |
| 4 | 4 | Cash | 5000 | 2022-12-15 18:44:16.783 |
| 5 | 5 | Cash | 30000 | 2022-12-15 18:44:16.783 |
| 6 | 5 | Cheque | 30000 | 2022-12-15 18:44:16.783 |

My Query :

```
SELECT cu.Crowdfund_id,
       sum(cu.Amount),
       sum(cp.Amount)
FROM [Crowdfund].[dbo].[Crowdfund_Users] cu
inner join Crowdfund_Payments cp on cu.ID=cp.Crowdfund_User_ID
group by cu.Crowdfund_id
```

Return :

| Crowdfund_id | TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Users | TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Payments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 203 | 138500.00 | 78500 |

Expected :

| Crowdfund_id | TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Users | TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Payments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 203 | 78500 | 78500 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your query is that , for ID =  5 you have two payments and by joining users with payments , like your case,   you are doubling the records in User table  and them summing it...

| Crowdfund_id | ID | Amount | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 203 | 5 | 60000 | 30000 |
| 203 | 5 | 60000 | 30000 |

You can try this:

First, you have to calculate the sum of the payments, by users , from `Crowdfund_Payments` like this:

```
   SELECT Crowdfund_User_ID,
          sum(cp.Amount) as Amount
   FROM dbo.Crowdfund_Payments cp
   GROUP BY Crowdfund_User_ID
```

with the result set:

| Crowdfund_User_ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 10000 |
| 3 | 3000 |
| 4 | 5000 |
| 5 | 60000 |

Joining this result set with table `Crowdfund_Users`:

```
  SELECT cu.Crowdfund_id,
        cu.ID ,
        cu.Amount as Amount_CU,
        cp.Amount as Amount_CP
  FROM  dbo.Crowdfund_Users cu
   inner join
  (SELECT Crowdfund_User_ID,
          sum(cp.Amount) as Amount
   FROM dbo.Crowdfund_Payments cp
  GROUP BY Crowdfund_User_ID
   )as cp on cu.ID=cp.Crowdfund_User_ID
```

will get  one record per user per Fund_ID:

| Crowdfund_id | ID | Amount_CU | Amount_CP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 203 | 1 | 500 | 500 |
| 203 | 2 | 10000 | 10000 |
| 203 | 3 | 3000 | 3000 |
| 203 | 4 | 5000 | 5000 |
| 203 | 5 | 60000 | 60000 |

Now, just Aggregate it (sum) with out cu.ID :

```
SELECT cus.Crowdfund_id,
       cus.Amount_CU AS TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Users,
       cus.Amount_CP AS TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Payments
FROM
  (
   SELECT cu.Crowdfund_id, 
          /*cu.ID ,*/ 
          SUM(cu.Amount) AS Amount_CU,
          SUM(cp.Amount) AS Amount_CP
   FROM dbo.Crowdfund_Users cu
   INNER JOIN
     (
      SELECT Crowdfund_User_ID,
             sum(cp.Amount) AS Amount
      FROM dbo.Crowdfund_Payments cp
      GROUP BY Crowdfund_User_ID
     )AS cp 
         ON cu.ID=cp.Crowdfund_User_ID
   GROUP BY cu.Crowdfund_id
  )AS cus
```

dbfiddle  [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1t7k7uNn)

output:

| Crowdfund_id | TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Users | TotalAmountIn_Crowdfund_Payments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 203 | 78500 | 78500 |